# How to calculate autograd.grad in pytorch internally?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I tried to get a grad in pytorch.
So, I coded it like below:

```
x = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
y = x * x

torch.autograd.grad(y, x, torch.tensor([2., 2., 2.])
```

Output:

```
tensor([4., 8., 12.])
```

How was it calculated internally?

I didn't know exactly why should I specify 'grad_outputs' as paramerter in torch.autograd.grad() and how was it computed.

Comment: I can recommend you this official tutorial on `autograd`: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html